# iPhone app that will navigate to a point on OSM maps in real time

Tags: maps, gps-navigation, software

I have an old eTrex that I use this way - 
I click a certain point on a map, where I want to go.
eTrex will:

- calculate a route and start giving me directions based on the map I preloaded it (usually OpenStreetMap downloaded).
- While navigating it will tell me distance to end of route and each turn or waypoint and will recalculate the route if I wander too far.

My question is - Is there an app that does this for the iPhone?
Closest I found is `Maps 3D Pro` but it's missing some of the features I described.

Thanks!

Comment: OSM = Open Street Map?

Comment: Yeah. I'll edit the post if it's not clear enough....

Comment: Any reason to use OSM over Google Maps? GMaps now fully support offline navigation and search.

Comment: Osm has far many more trails than google, at least where I live.

Comment: There's a chance you might have more luck with this on Outdoors.SE

Comment: Or maybe [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the app [“GPS Navigation (Sat Nav)”](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gps-navigation-sat-nav/id370144231). [It uses OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPS_Navigation_%26_Maps), and the maps are available offline (one country map is included in the price of the app, you need to pay extra for additional maps, currently it’s $10.99 for the whole world). You can tap a location on the map and get directions for going there, with different options for driving, walking or cycling (works offline too). You can view the directions as an overview map, or as a moving map that follows you and gives turn-by-turn directions, including the remaining distance. The app recalculates the directions automatically if you’re wandering off. One quirk the app has is that you may still get messages about the need for an internet connection, even if you turned on the “offline” option in the app; but the maps and directions do work offline.

You might also want to try [Pocket Earth](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocket-earth-offline-maps/id512924747) (free), [it also uses OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PocketEarth) and allows downloading the maps for offline use (requires an in-app purchase, currently $5.99 for the whole world). It can offer navigation directions, though you need to be online for it to calculate a route, which you can then save for offline use. If you wander off, it’s limited to warning you about it if you’re offline, it can only recalculate the route if you’re online. See the section “Routes & Navigation” in the [Pocket Earth Help Manual](https://pocketearth.com/help/) for details.

There’s a [table of iOS apps on the OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS), including [details on the navigation features of the apps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Navigating_features). The above two apps are the ones from the table I’m familiar with and which offer some navigation features. Perhaps another app more closely matches the feature set you’re looking for.